# After reboot my wlan0 disappeared and keep getting a disconnected message, how can I bring it up again?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I am using a Zotac ZBOX IQ-01 with Ubuntu 14.04 on it. It had been working alright, until I rebooted it and a message saying the net had disconnected started to appear on startup. The available WiFi nets no longer appear, and if I try:

```
$ ifcongig
```

the following appears:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:4e:fb:da  
      inet addr:192.168.2.114  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::201:2eff:fe4e:fbda/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:691 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:242341 (242.3 KB)  TX bytes:136667 (136.6 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:01:2e:4e:fb:db  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:52103 (52.1 KB)  TX bytes:52103 (52.1 KB)
```

as you can see wlan0 is no longer visible, and after doing

```
$ iwconfig
```

I get:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

If I try:

```
lspci
```

I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

The WiFi adapter is a Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 Model: 3160HMW. It seems to also be a Bluetooth controller, but the Bluetooth seems to keep working without problems.

What happened? What can I do? Is it a hardware failure? Perhaps the controller failed after an upgrade?
 Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the iwlwifi module is loaded. You can do this by typing:

```
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
```

If the result is empty, try typing:

```
modprobe iwlwifi
```

If that doesnt restore your wifi adapter, try typing

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

And see if that gives you any hints on to why you are still having issues.

Comment: It seems as if it was a hardware issue, the GPU's heatsink is just above the wi-fi antenna. We were testing some image processing so it got hot... We have used the warranty so everything seems ok now, thank you!